# OData wrapper around SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, signalr, odata

This may seem a little crazy, but while reading about OData I've come across some articles that claim run of the mill WCF Web Services can be exposed as OData endpoints (via some black magic or other).

The thing is, it may be practical for me to expose a SignalR web service with an OData endpoint.  Is this something that is possible to do with the currently available frameworks?  The SignalR service is used to extract data from one of the connected clients known as a "provider" which multiple consuming clients can request data from.

**Edit -**

I have a set of existing SignalR hubs for each type of entity (or **resource** in terms of OData), and each of these `Hubs` expose methods in a similar fashion to a `Repository` eg.

```
public class CustomersHub : Hub
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerData> GetCustomers( )
    public IEnumerable<CustomerData> GetCustomers(IEnumerable<int> ids);

    // with odata this method may not be necessary.
    public IEnumerable<CustomerData> FindCustomersByName(IEnumerable<string> names);
    /// ...
}
```

Hopefully this shows a striking resemblance to `ODataController` derived classes.  In this situation the `Hubs` are the **resources**.

Something very similar to what I am asking for was implemented for *WCF Data Services* in the *[WCF Data Service Toolkit](http://lostintangent.tumblr.com/post/3189655590/you-want-to-wrap-odata-around-what)* which AFAIK isn't active anymore, plus I'm trying to do this with SignalR.

If you ask why I am using SignalR for this type of service, it is because the data does not reside on the server the Web Service is hosted on, certain clients connected to the Web Service have that data.  Inside the methods is a call to another client (besides the `Caller`) who is sent a request for the data.

Answer (score 2):

From [the official OData specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html) (Introduction):

*The Open Data Protocol (OData) enables the creation of **REST-based data services**, which allow **resources**, identified using **Uniform Resource Locators** (URLs) and defined in a data model, to be published and edited by Web clients **using simple HTTP messages**. This specification defines the core semantics and the behavioral aspects of the protocol.*

None of this characteristics maps over SignalR, which is a realtime, **non-resource-based** technology based on a variety of HTTP/HTML techniques/hacks in order to **push** information. You can of course use SignalR to implement something along the lines of what you described, but as long as that would not implement a REST and purely HTTP-based request/response approach (and with SignalR it would not), that would not be OData by definition. Have a look at the specs and you will quickly see how that does not map over SignalR.

**UPDATE**

Even after your edit, it does not make sense to me. It's like you want some magic happening to enable you using walkie-talkies through the post office just because you can query their catalog.

Maybe you should distinguish your clients in *consumers* and *producers*, offer OData endpoints to the formers and hubs to the others, and do the necessary "magic" yourself.

Also, with SignalR I don't think you would have any IQueryable support needed to have out of the box OData plumbing.

Comment: *Maybe you should distinguish your clients in consumers and producers, offer OData endpoints to the formers and hubs to the others, and do the necessary "magic" yourself.* -- This is exactly what I want to do, my question is how to go about doing the "magic"

Comment: My understanding was that you was expecting to *use* some magic, which does not exist, not to actually write it. If you want/have to write, it it could be done in many ways and it could depend on many constraints you might have. I do not really have an answer, it would mean to think about your actual *detailed* requirements, think about it, design it... Sorry, no simple answer here.

Comment: OP wants to use SignalR as a transport INSTEAD of HTTP.

I've done this to lower latency introduced by connection overhead.

Comment: @ElanHasson I understand that, but he also wants to use OData, which by definition works with HTTP only according to docs. You can do as many *hacks* as you want and "make it work", but it's not OData anymore by definition (a *standard* client would not be able to consume it). Unless you have 2 different endpoints, but at that point it's really 2 different implementations side by side.

Comment: I agree. I believe he meant the protocol.  It is essentially an RPC model.

The gain may not be worth the effort.